# How I need show not saling product within 5 day compare with purchase date?

Tags: sql, oracle

How compare between date purchase and sale by product? How I need show not saling product within 5 day or more 5 day compare with purchase date?

```
Example 
ID  Direction  DateTrans    Product   QTY
1      IN      01.01.2016    ItemA     5 
2      IN      03.01.2016    ItemB     5 
3      IN      05.01.2016    ItemA     5 
4      OUT     04.01.2016    ItemB     5
```

> I need show select for current date  15.01.2016
>        passDay computed column calculated different day between currentdate and dateTrans

```
ID  Direction  DateTrans    Product   QTY    PassDay
1      IN      01.01.2016    ItemA     5     14 day
3      IN      05.01.2016    ItemA     5     11 day
```

This not show because already sold

```
2      IN      03.01.2016    ItemB     5
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand your logic.  Can you try fixing the explanation?  For instance, your data has no columns that seem to be "purchase date" or "sale date".  The calculation of `PassDay` also isn't described.

Comment: What's the expected result if QTY doesn't match? E.g. if sold ItemB is 3 instead of 5? Or if there also is a sold ItemA 7?

Comment: If qty 0 or 3 does not matter exclude

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show an IN record because there is an OUT record for the same product with a date later then the date of the IN record and within 5 days....

```
select ...
from your_table p_in
where p_in.direction='IN'
and not exists (select 1 
                from your_table p_out
                where p_out.direction='OUT'
                and p_out.product=p_in.product
                and p_out.datatrans-p_in.datetrans between 0 and 5)
```

Comment: Thank you I do like this  Thank you i do like this <b>not exists (select 1 
                from your_table p_out
                where p_out.direction='OUT'
                and p_out.product=p_in.product
                and p_out.datatrans>=p_in.datetrans</br>